# regarding the I( ) term in linear regression modeling in R using lm

Tags: r, statistics, regression, lm

I once saw a linear model fitting written as follows:

```
lm(formula = Ozone ~ Solar.R + Wind + Temp + I(Wind^2) + I(Temp^2) + 
I(Wind * Temp) + I(Wind * Temp^2) + I(Temp * Wind^2) + I(Temp^2 * 
Wind^2), data = airquality)
```

I am not sure what does `I( )` mean here? Or for example, what does `I(Wind * Temp^2)` here. can I write it as `Wind:Temp^2`?

Comment: My understanding is that it means 'do this calculation first'.

Comment: `Wind^2` means second order interactions, while `I(Wind^2)` means the square of Wind.

Comment: Do I have to put I() before the Wind^2?

Comment: FWIW it may be worth investigating the `poly()` function: `poly(Wind,Temp,degree=3)` constructs a 3d-order polynomial including all terms up to order 3 (`Wind`, `Temp`, `Wind^2`, `Temp^2`, `Wind*Temp`, `Wind^3`, `Wind*Temp^2`, `Wind^2*Temp`, `Temp^3`)

Answer (score 7):

The `I()` notation in the formula syntax in R means **'as is'** i.e. `I(a+b)` simply means add the variable a+b as a predictor in the lm model. In your case `I(Wind * Temp^2)` means include as a predictor variable the product of Wind and Temp squared. The `I()` function is used so that there is no confusion with the operators of the formula syntax.

For more info page 2 [here](http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/richard.hahn/teaching/FormulaNotation.pdf) explains it in full detail.

Hope this is clear!

**UPDATE**
I just want to add Hong Ooi's very good comment on this:

`I(Wind * Temp^2)` **is not the same as** Wind:Temp^2

The `^n` operator in formula syntax means **'include these variables and all interactions up to n way'**. For example `Y ~ (X + Z + W)^2` is equivalent to `Y ~ X + Z + W + X:Z + X:W + Z:W`

So, in our case `Wind:Temp^2` means just `Wind:Temp`

Small illustration:

```
Y <- runif(100)
X1 <- runif(100)
X2 <- runif(100)
df <- data.frame(Y,X1,X2)

> b <- lm( Y ~ X1:X2^2,data=df)
> summary(b)

Call:
lm(formula = Y ~ X1:X2^2, data = df)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.4802 -0.2490 -0.0173  0.2345  0.5066 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.45126    0.04794   9.413 2.28e-15 ***
X1:X2        0.08991    0.13414   0.670    0.504    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.2965 on 98 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.004563,  Adjusted R-squared:  -0.005594 
F-statistic: 0.4493 on 1 and 98 DF,  p-value: 0.5043
```